# how upgrade jdk?

Tags: upgrade, android, jdk, android-studio, android-sdk

I need upgrade my jdk to the newest one.

Case in that, i have downloaded new Android Studio 2.1 and get such issue

[image]

if i go according to the [link](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/preview/setup-sdk.html#java8), i realize that my jdk version not compatible with android studio 2.1...

eventually my old jdk lie in `/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_65`, say me please which commands i should input in order to upgrade my JDK?

Thaks for suggest

Here screenshot with synaptic

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i have found solution. Issue was in this case, i were needed change the environment variable, the first open the file :

```
sudo nano  /etc/environment
```

and next step is add this line :

```
JAVA_HOME=(your path to JDK)
```

in my case was :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

and all is work

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your current java installation and do the following:

Insert the webupd8team java ppa to your system (as root):

add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

apt-get update

Install both oracle-java8-installer and oracle-java8-set-default.
This will keep your JDK updated whenever new versions are released by Oracle.

Comment: Sorry but i am a rookie in android... Issue is that, i can't delete current installation ... I don't know why, it didn't have such properties... Maybe i should try with help of terminal, but which command?

Comment: How did you make your current installation?

Comment: it was downloaded concurrently with Android Studio...

Comment: That's strange.  I've been using Android Studio for at least a year and the zip file I downloaded from the Android developers site never had anything other than Android studio itself.

Anyway, check if you're using OpenJDK instead and if yes, you can uninstall it easily using synaptic.

Comment: Yes i use Open JDK OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
But you said it is easily uninstall, but how?(( i haven't used synaptic before...

Comment: i have found and install sunaptic by this command sudo apt-get install synaptic

Comment: I hava added screenshot from synaptic, issue is that should i delete all components which are connectid with OpenJDK? Sorry for a lot of questions...

Comment: it is a problem even if i marked Open JDK as a Complitely delete i can't apply changes... How do you think it will be a problem if i upload new one according your advice without deleting old ?

Comment: Ok.  Normally you should not install two concurrent java packages on the same system and it would be better if you could remove openJDK.

It's strange synaptic cannot apply those changes.  Since you managed to install synaptic using apt-get, I guess you can use it again to remove openJDK too.

Try this command as root: apt-get purge openjdk* default-jre icedtea* ca-certificates-java.  I am not sure all of the packages above are actually installed on your system, so you may get messages like, this or that is not installed, but that's ok.  I'm just making sure you purge all of them.